# SQL Query Filter Top 1 Row from Table 2 based on Latest Date for each type in Table 1

Tags: sql, join

From Table1, get all the records filtered by Type that contain '0x' and display the respective CaseID, DocID and Date from Table2. From Table2, only get the top 1 record based on the latest date.

I need to write a sql query to get the output. Kindly assist.

Table1

```
ID | Name | Type  | Description
1  | A    | 0x100 | Description Text 1
2  | B    | 0x200 | Description Text 2
3  | C    | 0x300 | Description Text 3
4  | D    | XYS   | Description Text 4
```

Table 2

```
CaseID | DocID | Type  | Date
A1     | 1     | 0x100 | 4/28/2014
A2     | 2     | 0x100 | 4/29/2014
A3     | 3     | 0x100 | 4/30/2014
A4     | 4     | 0x100 | 5/1/2014
A5     | 5     | 0x100 | 5/2/2014
A6     | 1     | 0x200 | 3/3/2015
A7     | 2     | 0x200 | 3/1/2015
A8     | 3     | 0x300 | 1/1/2015
A9     | 4     | 0x300 | 1/2/2015
A10    | 5     | 0x300 | 1/3/2015
A11    | 11    | 0x300 | 1/4/2015
```

Result

```
ID | Name | Type  | Description        | CaseID | DocID | Date
1  | A    | 0x100 | Description Text 1 | A5     | 5     | 5/2/2014
2  | B    | 0x200 | Description Text 2 | A6     | 1     | 3/3/2015
3  | C    | 0x300 | Description Text 3 | A11    | 11    | 1/4/2015
```

Comment: what db are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following (tested!):

```
SELECT
    t1.Name, t1.Type, t1.Description, t2.CaseID, t2.DocID, t2.Date
FROM
    (SELECT Type, MAX(Date) AS MaxDate FROM Table2 GROUP BY Type) AS t2max -- FIRST
    JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t2max.Type = t2.Type AND t2max.MaxDate = t2.Date -- SECOND
    JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t2.Type = t1.Type -- THIRD
WHERE
    t2.type LIKE '0x%'
ORDER BY
    t1.Name;
```

Okay, explanation: First, the query engine looks at the from clause. There are three tables in there that it's going to join together. The first is created by a subquery; it is the Type/Date pairs for the top records in table 2 by date. The second is the rest of table2; we join these two together to so that we now have all columns in table2 at our disposal. Then third table in the from clause is table1, and we join that to our current row source on the Type column. At this point, we've got a row source with columns from the subquery, from table2 and from table1. The query engine next filters out the rows we don't want; the ones that aren't in the desired '0x%' format. The select clause states that we only want particular columns from the row source in the result set, so it the query engine grabs those, sorts them as per the order by clause, and spits out the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t.ID
    ,t.Name
    ,t.Type
    ,t.Description
    ,t2.CaseID
    ,t2.DocID
  ,MAX(t2.Date) as DocDate
FROM Table1 AS t
JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t.Type = t2.Type
WHERE t.Type like '0x%'
GROUP BY t.ID
    ,t.Name
    ,t.Type
    ,t.Description
    ,t2.CaseID
    ,t2.DocID
HAVING t2.Date = MAX(t2.Date)
```

Do I read you correctly?

Comment: I got the solution for the above problem.                                                  select 
     AllRows.ID,
     AllRows.Name,
     AllRows.Type,
     AllRows.Description,
     AllRows.CaseID,
     AllRows.DocID,
     AllRows.Date
 from
 (
 select 
     Table1.ID,
     Table1.Name,
     Table1.Type,
     Table1.Description,
     Table2.CaseID,
     Table2.DocID,
     Table2.Date, 
     row_number()over(partition by Table1.Type order by Table2.[Date] desc) as rn
 from Table1
 join Table2 on Table2.[Type] = Table1.[Type]
 where
     Table1.Type like '0x%'
 ) AllRows
 
 where rn =1